# Same page CORB blocked in one instance but not another

Tags: javascript, html, cross-origin-read-blocking

On a website, I frequently load an HTML containing an image viewer into an iframe by setting `iframe/@source` to the target address.

Usually, this works fine, e.g. http://dev2.hab.de/edoc/view.html?id=edoc_ed000216_f010_transcript displays the requested page (http://diglib.hab.de/show_image.php?dir=drucke/li-10249&distype=imgs&image=00033) just fine.

But right next door, if http://dev2.hab.de/edoc/view.html?id=edoc_ed000244_f02-widmungsvorrede tries to load the exact same page, I get an error in Chrome (67.0):

```
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response 
http://diglib.hab.de/show_image.php?dir=drucke/li- 
    10249&distype=imgs&image=00033 with MIME type text/html.
```

Firefox (60.0.2) also shows the page in the first but not the second case but does not even display any message in the console.

Any ideas whether I missed something obvious or any other hints are highly appreciated.